# How to use STM32Cube Static Stack Analyzer as an automatic compile time sanity check?

Tags: stm32, memory, stm32cubeide

I'm currently using the STM32Cube IDE to develop a project.  It automatically runs the static stack analyzer every time I compile the project, but I've found if the stack size exceeds the total RAM of the chip it does not provide any error or warning.  I can keep an eye on it manually, but it's easy for this to slip by.  I'd like to find a way to create an compile time check fir this, but I'm not sure how to access the results programmatically.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting idea, but also quite difficult to make a useful fix...

- The static stack analyzer analyses the stack usage of all the "entry points" in the code relying on su-files (produced by C compiler).
- Assembler files are not analyzed and does not produce su-files, consequently we don't know the local stack cost for assembler functions.
- Also function pointers that changes at run-time can by nature not be analyzed at build-time which further sets some constraints.
- In RTOS based system each thread has its own stack, this is not known by GCC at compile-time and certainly not visualized well...

Because of all these reasons it is hard to predict at compile-time an accurate picture of the stack usage of your application. The Static Stack Usage view, provides valuable insights. But these insights are not "global" enough to solve your issue.

That said, we will thinks about it.
You can use the the static stack analyzer to get some insights, based on this information try to set the link-time guard symbols in the linker script to set a reasonable limit:

- _Min_Heap_Size = 0x200; /* required amount of heap*/
- _Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

Doing so, you will at least get a link-time error when you: .data + .bss + .heap + "estimated stack usage" > RAM size.